# detecting equivalence of typedefs

Tags: c++, typedef, declaration

In my application, I have a type responsible for computations that (may) involve large numbers and a type that is used for communication between processors.

```
typedef MyBigIntegerClass bigInt;
typedef int smallInt;
```

The communication part ist not compatible with MyBigIntegerClass, so before communicating e.g. a vector of bigInts it has to be converted to smallints. So far, no problem at all.

However, for most problem instances, the use of MyBigIntegerClass isn't necessary. In fact, even `int32_t` is sufficient. This is why I allow a configuration such as

```
typedef int32_t bigInt;
typedef int16_t smallInt;
```

The bigInt type still is sufficiently large for the computation stuff. The problem with this is, that smallInt has to differ from bigInt.

```
class Problematic
{
    public:
       Problematic(bigInt);
       Problematic(smallInt);
};
```

In this class, constructors or methods may either take bigInts or smallInts. If they are the same, compilation fails.

Since other users of the code might want to adjust the used types, they may end up with a configuration such as

```
typedef int32_t bigInt;
typedef int32_t smallInt;
```

and compilation fails in a (for at least some developers) non-obvious way.

One way of dealing with this would be `static_assert(sizeof(bigInt) != sizeof(smallint), "bad config..")`, but I actually like the possibility of having `bigInt == smallInt`. What would be a good way to change the declaration of `class Problematic` to allow equivalence of the types?

Answer (score 2):

If it is desirable to retain both the constructors a possible solution is wrap the `int` types in templates which means they are different types always, even if the underlying `int` type is the same:

```
template <typename T>
struct big_int
{
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
struct small_int
{
    T value;
};

typedef big_int<long> bigInt;
typedef small_int<long> smallInt;

class Problematic
{
public:
    Problematic(bigInt) {}
    Problematic(smallInt) {}
};
```

Compiles when underlying types are the same (http://ideone.com/KGz9Vk) and when they are not the same (http://ideone.com/Pt0XGS).

To allow `big_int<>` and `small_int<>` to behave as integral types implementations of the operators are required. For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct big_int
{
    T value;
    operator T() { return value; }

    big_int& operator+=(big_int const& other)
    {
        value += other.value;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename U>
    big_int& operator+=(U const& v)
    {
        value += v;
        return *this;
    }

    big_int& operator++()
    {
        ++value;
        return *this;
    }

    big_int operator++(int)
    {
        big_int temp = *this;
        ++value;
        return temp;
    }
};
```

This is not exhaustive (see http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/ for useful guidance on implementing operators). See http://ideone.com/xlE2Mi for example.

Comment: This is certainly a nice way, to have a distinction between the types. However it seems to break the usual interface (such as comparison with integers). Any idea on how to avoid this without reimplementing the whole interface in `template struct small_int`?

Comment: @stefan, for comparision with integers add a conversion operator to the `template`s: `operator T() { return value; }`.

Comment: @stefan, you need to implement the required operators then. Will update with example shortly.

Comment: well yes, I know how to implement all this, but I hoped for a cleaner way. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @stefan, no problem. I am unware of a cleaner way to do this, unfortunately.